# Getting NULL value from sessionStorage.getItem() Angular 7

Tags: angular

I created a service where I am calling an API to get User Detail and adding received information in `Session Storage`, but when I am calling `sessionStorage.getItem('username')` getting null in response.

```
getUserDetail(email: string, password: string) {
        this.httpClient.get<User[]>('http://localhost/user/user_login?email=' + email + '&password=' + password).pipe(map(
            (user) => {
                return user;
            }

        )).subscribe(
            (user: User[]) => {
                if (user['isUser'] == true) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('username', user['username']);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('userid', user['userid']);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('password', password);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('email', email);
                    this.router.navigate(['/homepage']);
                } else {
                    console.log(user['error']);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('login_error', user['error']);
                }
            }

        );
        console.log('User From Login: ' + sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    }
```

I also set variables in `environment` there also not fetching values after routing, But when I refresh page, I get the values properly.

environment.ts file code.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseURL: 'http://localhost/user/',
  credentialHeaders:
  {
    'email': sessionStorage.getItem('email'),
    'password': sessionStorage.getItem('password')
  }
};
```

And when I call this api in my Service.

```
this.httpClient.get<List[]>(this.baseURL + 'data_list/get_all_list', { headers: environment.credentialHeaders })
```

I get the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

This error is for Headers.

Comment: When you put the data into the session storage and when you then open up developer tools of your browser and inspect sessions storage in the application tab (chrome) do you see your data there?

Comment: What is the point of the `map` operation here, BTW?

Comment: @arnonuem Yeah I can see session data there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `environment` to set session values, it was not working, I think environment load only once and any new values not initialize there in `environment`.

Now I set my values in a shared `Service` and fetching that values everywhere, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you `getItem` before you `setItem` it. You code basically does this:

```
// send and asynchronous request here
        this.httpClient.get<User[]>(/* args */)
            .subscribe(/* stuff to be done AFTER request comes back,
                          including storing username in session storage */);

// and here we are outside the subscription, the line below gets executed in the same
// event loop tick that the request is sent, long before it comes back.
        console.log('User From Login: ' + sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
```

Comment: Yeah that's Okay, You are saying right. But when I am accessing the same session values in environment, there also getting NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting data from the server asynchronously by calling the `httpClient.get()` but you're trying to get the value synchronously by checking the `sessionStorage` before the call came back:

`console.log('User From Login: ' + sessionStorage.getItem('username'));`

You should move above line inside the subscribe method.

Comment: Yeah that's Okay, You are saying right. But when I am accessing the same session values in environment, there also getting NULL.

Comment: it depends on the moment you view the environment, in any case you should read the value asynchronously as well